# Erro utf-8 phpmailler

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte classe para envio de emails:

```
<?php

  class EmailEnviarDao {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function enviaEmail($email)  {

      $enviaFormularioParaNome = $email->getNomeAlvo();
      $enviaFormularioParaEmail = $email->getEmailAlvo();

      $caixaPostalServidorNome = 'Hotplate Prensas';
      $caixaPostalServidorEmail = 'contato@hotplateprensas.com.br';
      $caixaPostalServidorSenha = '1234567890';

      $remetenteNome  = $email->getNomeRemete();
      $remetenteEmail = $email->getEmailRemete();
      $mensagem = $email->getDescricao();
      $assunto =  $email->getAssunto();
      $qual =  $email->getQual();

      $mensagemConcatenada = '<!doctype html>
                              <html>
                              <head>
                                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                                <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
                                <title>'.$caixaPostalServidorNome.'</title>
                              </head>
                              <body>
                                Formulário gerado via website<br/><br/><br/>
                                Nome: '.$remetenteNome.'<br/>
                                E-mail: '.$remetenteEmail.'<br/>
                                Assunto: '.$qual=="" ? $assunto : $qual.'<br/>
                                -------------------------------<br/><br/>
                                Mensagem: '.$mensagem.' 
                              </body>';

      $mail = new PHPMailer();

      $mail->IsSMTP();
      $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;
      $mail->Charset   = 'UTF-8';
      $mail->Host  = 'smtp.'.substr(strstr($caixaPostalServidorEmail, '@'), 1);
      $mail->Port  = '587';
      $mail->Username  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
      $mail->Password  = $caixaPostalServidorSenha;
      $mail->From  = $remetenteEmail;
      $mail->FromName  = $remetenteNome;
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject  = $assunto == "Outro Assunto" ? $qual : $assunto;
      $mail->Body  = $mensagemConcatenada; 
      $mail->AddAddress($enviaFormularioParaEmail,utf8_decode($enviaFormularioParaNome));

      if($mail->Send()){

          return array("success"=>1,"errors"=>"0K");

      } else {

          return array("success"=>0,"errors"=>"Não conseguimos enviar o e-mail");

      }    
    }   

  }

?>
```

Tudo funciona bem, menos os acentos.

Já tentei diversas alternativas aqui publicadas no fórum mas nenhuma deu certo.

O e-mail é disparado. Mas os acentos, não!

Tentei colocar o UTF-8 no htmls e no

Comment: utf8_decode($mensagemConcatenada);

Comment: obrigado. deu certo!

Comment: Blz, vou colocar como resposta

Answer (score 1):

> Simplesmente use [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php) na variavel desejada;

**Acredito que no seu caso seja** `utf8_decode($mensagemConcatenada);`

Comment: blz. mas agora surgiu uma dúvida: quando fazemos: $mail->Charset   = 'UTF-8'; isso não deveria ser capaz de resolver o problema?

Comment: @CarlosRocha, você experimentou `$mail->Charset = 'UTF-8';` ?

Comment: no meu código já tinha isso e não funcionou. veja na pergunta

Comment: @CarlosRocha acredito que o correto deva ser `$mail = new PHPMailer(); $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";`  Você tem que colocá-lo após a instanciação do objeto.

Comment: A diferença para o meu código é na letra S (de CharSet) maiúscula ou nas aspas duplas?]

Comment: @CarlosRocha, você queria uma solução ou fazer testes com possibilidades?

Comment: Não amigo.A dúvida é que no meu código já havia essa a chamada ao charset. Porem escrito ->charset e não CharSet igual ao teu. . Outra coisa é que no teu, o UTF-8 está com aspas duplas e no meu com aspas simples

Comment: @CarlosRocha o correto é CharSet, as aspas tanto faz! Com CharSet funcionou? Tem alguma coisa nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491475/phpmailer-character-encoding-issues